# Using docker into the jenkinsci/blueocean image

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

### Context

I'm on Ubuntu and I want to run the official Jenkins image (i.e., `jenkinsci/blueocean`) into a docker container. I need also to allow the containerized Jenkins to access the Docker daemon on the host (i.e., Ubuntu).

Using docker in docker has security [problems](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/). The alternative is just exposing the Docker socket to the container. Here is how I do it into my docker-compose:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

### Problem

The problem with this approach is that the `docker` GID among host and container is inconsistent. On the host side, the `docker` group is `999` but in the container it is `101` (`999` is the GID of the group `ping`, I guess this happens since this container is built on top of Alpine). Indeed:

```
# This is the container shell, the group is ping
bash-4.4$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root ping 0 Apr  8 16:20 /var/run/docker.sock
```

### Temporary fix (manual)

In order to fix I have just to open up a shell in the container as `root` and launch:

```
bash-4.4$ apk --no-cache add shadow
bash-4.4$ usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

And I'm done.

### What I need

I need a programmatic fix to have docker up & running inside the official container when I spin it up. During the build phase, I cannot run `usermod -aG docker jenkins` since `/var/run/docker.sock` does not exist in the official image but it is bind-mounted later on at runtime.

Is there a way to fix it programmatically the first time the container runs?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is a hack, and also violation of single responsibility (concern) principle for each container, because you probably want to add other applications into the container that has jerkins container in it. (https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/cloud-native-container-design-whitepaper) This is going to cause you other problems in the future with  CPU usage, volumes, network. Instead, you need to let jenkinsci/blueocean run its own container in your host.

Comment: I understand this point of view. However,  I need to allow jenkins to work with docker and putting docker in docker is even worse.

Comment: You should be able to add jenkins to the user group event if the docker socket is not mounted (you may need to create the docker group yoursef). I have done it on the jenkins image and I am trying to do it on the jenkinsci/blueocean image but I am not able for now because of problem describe here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032826/how-to-add-jenkins-to-docker-group-inside-jenkinsci-blueocean-image